# Username in URL and cache

Tags: php, apache, url, caching

On my site I allow users to change their usernames. Usernames are used in URLs of their profiles.
On my frontpage there are many blocks which contain usernames and links to profiles (new users, last comments, best photos, new posts etc). I want to cache this page. But how to handle with usernames? What if a user changed his username and cache has not expired yet? Then there would be possible 404 errors.
Using of user ids in their profile urls would solve the problem, but this is undesirable.
How to revalidate cache in this situation? Maybe are there some tricks?

I consider a pattern for url like `site.com/123/username` but it's also undesirable. I want nice and short pattern `site.com/username`

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is possible to remove page cache programmatically. Try this:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/pages/somePage.aspx");
```

Then, when user hits the page, cache should be updated with new usernames etc.

Also you can use CacheItemDependency. Check the article: http://aspalliance.com/668

This is definitely the solution

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a PHP tag, but I think your answer a can bring some clues, спасибо)).